# NodeJs JavaScript heap out of memory crash on react-scripts-ts after adding tests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have an react + typescript project. Since a couple of days ago, my webstorm IDE crashes( JavaScript heap out of memory) [on every update that I make to codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420822/nodejs-frequent-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-crash-on-react-scripts-ts). I'm using nodeJs 12.3.1, typescript 3.7.5, react 16.12.0, react-scripts-ts 3.1.0, webstorm 2021.2 and my OS is windows 10.

The only significant change I made since that time is adding a bunch of tests(48 tests with 5000 line of codes to be exact). These tests are written using jest and enzyme. These tests include mocking some APIs and events, and mounting elements to check their existence and status. I should say that all of these tests will be passed.

My question is why nodeJs breaks after every change I make to code after this change? What does `react-scripts-ts start` do on `hot reloads`? Should I consider some specific hidden points when writing tests?

I would appreciate any help or clue to find the problem.

PS: I would be glad to share any necessary information to help clarifying the problem.

Here is a the code of one of these tests:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import DonutObjectKpi from './donutObjectKpi';
import {
  ChartType,
  DashboardItemType,
  DonutChartProps,
  NamedKpiSeriesSelector,
} from '../../../../utils/dashboardUtils/dashboardItem/props';
import KpiDefinition from '../../../../../model/kpi/customKpi/kpiDefinition';
import Kpi from '../../../../../model/kpi/kpi';
import KpiDefinitionType from '../../../../../model/kpi/kpiDefinitionType';
import { CHART_REFRESH_RATE } from '../../../../../config/constants';
import { Button, HorizontalLayout, IconButton, PieChartType, Table } from '../../../../view';
import { InputLabeledField } from '../../../../../modules/panels/baseCrud/layouts';
import { EnumDropDown } from '../../../../input';
import BuildOption from '../../../dropdown/buildOption/component';

enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
describe('ObjectKpiItem Test', () => {
  let chartType = ChartType.DONUT;
  let showTitle = true;
  let title: string | undefined = 'Test';
  let cancelModal: boolean = false;
  let dataModal: DonutChartProps | undefined;
  let changeType: boolean = false;
  const obj = {value: '1', label: 'item1'};
  const resourceObj = {value: '2', label: 'item2'};
  const kpiDef: KpiDefinition = {
    kpi: Kpi.DB2Z_DSCDBAT,
    type: KpiDefinitionType.OBJECT_KPI,
    monitoringObject: {id: '3', presentation: 'item3'},
  };
  const description = 'donut Test';

  const selectors: NamedKpiSeriesSelector[] = [
    {kpi: Kpi.ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_COMPUTERS_COUNT, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '1', objectIdName: 'item1'},
    {kpi: Kpi.ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DISABLED_USERS_COUNT, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '2', objectIdName: 'item2'},
    {kpi: Kpi.HBASE_REGION_SERVER_STORE_FILE_SIZE_20210, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '3', objectIdName: 'item3'},
  ];

  it('check render:', () => {
    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(
      <DonutObjectKpi
        onObjectKpiChartTypeChange={(newType, showTitleRes, titleRes) => {
          chartType = newType;
          showTitle = showTitleRes;
          title = titleRes;
        }}
        showTitle={showTitle}
        chartType={chartType}
        title={title}
        objectId={obj}
        onCancel={() => cancelModal = true}
        submitModal={(data: DonutChartProps) => dataModal = data}
        onDashboardItemTypeChange={() => changeType = true}
      />,
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(InputLabeledField).length).toEqual(8);
    expect(wrapper.find(Table).length).toEqual(2);
    expect(wrapper.find(IconButton).length).toEqual(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(EnumDropDown).length).toEqual(9); // 4 self + 5 border table
  });

  it('check change value:', () => {
    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(
      <DonutObjectKpi
        onObjectKpiChartTypeChange={(newType, showTitleRes, titleRes) => {
          chartType = newType;
          showTitle = showTitleRes;
          title = titleRes;
        }}
        showTitle={showTitle}
        chartType={chartType}
        title={title}
        objectId={obj}
        onCancel={() => cancelModal = true}
        submitModal={(data: DonutChartProps) => dataModal = data}
        onDashboardItemTypeChange={() => changeType = true}
        data={{
          title,
          showTitle: true,
          selectors,
          chartType: ChartType.DONUT,
          type: PieChartType.KPI,
          dashboardItemType: DashboardItemType.OBJECT_KPI,
          interval: CHART_REFRESH_RATE,
          description,
        }}
      />,
    );
    wrapper.setState({
      resourceId: resourceObj,
      kpiDefinition: kpiDef,
      objectId: obj,
      selectors,
      title,
    });
    wrapper.update();
    wrapper.find(IconButton).last().simulate('click');
    expect(dataModal).not.toEqual(undefined);
    expect(dataModal!.title).toEqual(title);
    expect(dataModal!.description).toEqual(description);
    expect(dataModal!.chartType).toEqual(chartType);
    expect(dataModal!.selectors.length).toEqual(selectors.length);
    expect(dataModal!.dashboardItemType).toEqual(DashboardItemType.OBJECT_KPI);
  });

  it('check cancel modal:', () => {
    const newObj = {value: '2', label: 'item2'};
    const newResourceObj = {value: '3', label: 'item3'};
    const newKpiDef: KpiDefinition = {
      kpi: Kpi.HBASE_REGION_SERVER_NUM_OF_HLOG_FILE_20206,
      type: KpiDefinitionType.OBJECT_KPI,
      monitoringObject: {id: '4', presentation: 'item4'},
    };

    const newSelectors: NamedKpiSeriesSelector[] = [
      {kpi: Kpi.ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_COMPUTERS_COUNT, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '1', objectIdName: 'item1'},
      {kpi: Kpi.ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DISABLED_USERS_COUNT, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '2', objectIdName: 'item2'},
      {kpi: Kpi.HBASE_REGION_SERVER_STORE_FILE_SIZE_20210, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '3', objectIdName: 'item3'},
      {kpi: Kpi.HBASE_REGION_SERVER_NUM_OF_REGIONS_20204, kpiDefinition: kpiDef, objectId: '4', objectIdName: 'item4'},
    ];

    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(
      <DonutObjectKpi
        onObjectKpiChartTypeChange={(newType, showTitleRes, titleRes) => {
          chartType = newType;
          showTitle = showTitleRes;
          title = titleRes;
        }}
        showTitle={showTitle}
        chartType={chartType}
        title={title}
        objectId={newObj}
        onCancel={() => cancelModal = true}
        submitModal={(data: DonutChartProps) => dataModal = data}
        onDashboardItemTypeChange={() => changeType = true}
        data={{
          title,
          showTitle: true,
          selectors,
          chartType: ChartType.DONUT,
          type: PieChartType.KPI,
          dashboardItemType: DashboardItemType.OBJECT_KPI,
          interval: CHART_REFRESH_RATE,
          description,
        }}
      />,
    );
    wrapper.setState({
      resourceId: newResourceObj,
      kpiDefinition: newKpiDef,
      objectId: newObj,
      selectors: newSelectors,
      title,
    });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(dataModal!.selectors.length).toEqual(selectors.length);
    expect(cancelModal).toEqual(false);
    wrapper.find(Button).at(1).simulate('click');
    expect(dataModal!.selectors.length).not.toEqual(newSelectors.length);
    expect(cancelModal).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('check change type:', () => {
    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(
      <DonutObjectKpi
        onObjectKpiChartTypeChange={(newType, showTitleRes, titleRes) => {
          chartType = newType;
          showTitle = showTitleRes;
          title = titleRes;
        }}
        showTitle={showTitle}
        chartType={chartType}
        title={title}
        objectId={obj}
        onCancel={() => cancelModal = true}
        submitModal={(data: DonutChartProps) => dataModal = data}
        onDashboardItemTypeChange={() => changeType = true}
        data={{
          title,
          showTitle: true,
          selectors,
          chartType: ChartType.DONUT,
          type: PieChartType.KPI,
          dashboardItemType: DashboardItemType.OBJECT_KPI,
          interval: CHART_REFRESH_RATE,
          description,
        }}
      />,
    );
    wrapper.find(InputLabeledField).first().find(EnumDropDown).first().find('div').at(1).simulate('click');
    const type = wrapper.find(InputLabeledField).first().find(EnumDropDown).first();
    expect(changeType).toEqual(false);
    type.find(BuildOption).first().find(HorizontalLayout).first().find('div').first().simulate('click');
    expect(changeType).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: I suggest you do some reading searching for `jest` observe `memory-leak`

this is something that you can find directly in the documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--logheapusage

and please have another look at the community guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who may have my problem, the workaround I found was to **exclude all test files from `typescript` compilation**. Here is the exclude section in my `tsconfig.json`(I have added last two lines):

```json
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
```

I should mention that optimizing tests with respect to memory usage did not help.